# boto3 not finding AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Tags: amazon-web-services, pycharm, credentials, boto3

I am setting `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` using command prompt.

I am using `PyCharm` as my IDE.

When I try to run any Python script that needs to talk to `AWS` using `Boto3`, PyCharm is not able to find `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. Even `os.environ` is not printing `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

Comment: How are you setting the environment variables exactly? Are you restarting PyCharm after setting those variables?

Comment: `set "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxx"
set "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxx"`. I tried restarting PyCharm but still no luck.

Comment: Try changing `set` to `export`

Comment: I am using windows. export gave me an error saying `'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Why not just set it in the Windows UI then? If you want to use command line I think you need to change `set` to `setx`.

Comment: do you use aws cli for setting credentials

Comment: sorry for the trouble guys. I had to set the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` in `PyCharm`'s environment variable. Its all working now.

Comment: Still this is a problem. Proxy only made the call go thru. Now I am getting specific error saying `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`.